# How to update the ganache server after forking, to always get the current/latest blocknumber (or blockchain state)?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, ganache

For some reason ganache does not update the forked local chain. And Because of that I get the "missing trie node" error sometimes.

Any ideas? Thx!

my ganache server code:

```
...
        let options = {
            fork:{
                url: fork_main_url,  
                blockNumber: 'latest',
                preLatestConfirmations: 0, //new
                requestsPerSecond: 0,
                deleteCache: true,
                disableCache: true,
            },
            logging: {
                quiet: true,
            },  
            miner: {//new
                blockTime: 0,
            },
            server: {
                ws: true,
            }
        }; 

            this.server = ganache.server(options); 
            this.server.listen(PORT);
...
```

Reforking and recreate the whole server when a new node is mined (see below). But it slows the all process.

```
provider.on('block', async(blckNr)=> {
...
})
```